# What explains the sharp drop-off in Republican vote share vs the 2020 presidential election in the 2021 NYC mayor primary?

Tags: united-states, demographics

Here are the primary results screenshotted from [RRH Elections](https://rrhelections.com/index.php/2021/06/22/new-york-2021-primary-elections-liveblog-livemap/):

[image: Democratic primary results]
[image: Republican primary results]

This same precinct cast 57 votes for Trump compared to 326 for Biden per [NYTimes](https://www.nytimes.com/interactive/2021/upshot/2020-election-map.html), and it swung 23 points towards the former president:

[image]

This is not isolated. I did this in multiple areas and I found the dropoff to be particularly severe in mostly Hispanic neighborhoods. I saw similar results occur in Louisiana’s 2nd jungle primary, but that could be explained by it being a safe Democratic seat and some of the relatively few Republicans there voted to lock out the progressive candidates.

I am wondering why it decreased *so much*. Trump won 57 out of 383 major party votes while the Republicans in the mayor race combined and therefore individually gave zero while 88 were cast in the Democratic primary for various candidates with Eric Adams winning a plurality.

Comment: Mail in voting is not reporting. But the mail in votes are unlikely to change the fact that this is a shutout voting district given that they skew overwhelmingly Democratic.

Comment: I think that just too many users react too agressively, expecting talks about voting results.. Though, question seems to be interesting. I've upvoted, but woudn't be expecting wall of upvotes.

Comment: Why does it surprise you that there was more interest in the highest turnout presidential election compared to an off-year mayoral primary for a candidate that has 0 chance of winning?

Comment: It doesn't. But the turnout is different and worthy of discussion.

Comment: @NumberFile - If you were comparing the current primary to the previous primary, then there might be an interesting comparison here.  Comparing it to _any_ non-primary is not going to produce useful information - the slice of the electorate that participates in each is just too different to be worth comparing other than in aggregate.  It's a bit like asking why Boeing vehicles are less fuel efficient than Ford vehicles - yes, they're both vehicles that consume fuel, so you _can_ compare them, but it doesn't tell you anything useful about either one.

Comment: @bobson I understand what you mean but this is a HUGE discrepancy that probably cant simply be explained like this

Comment: @NumberFile - In 2017, the previous mayoral primary, that precinct has 142 votes cast (including absentee and military votes and affidavits).  121 of them were Democratic, 6 were Republican.  ([Source](https://vote.nyc/sites/default/files/pdf/election_results/2017/20171107General%20Election/00001100000Citywide%20Mayor%20Citywide%20EDLevel.pdf)) If 88/142s of the same votes were cast in the democratic election, we'd expect 3.7 to be cast in the republican one.  I, personally, don't see a less-than-four-vote difference between years as a "HUGE discrepancy".

Comment: Put another way, it's equally valid to ask where the extra Republican votes in 2020 came from, since we'd only expect 16 based on the 2017 primary (142 -> 383 total; 121 -> 326.4 dem; 6 -> *16.1*, not 57, rep).  That's numerically a much bigger jump.

Comment: @NumberFile: If I understand your screenshots right, it's showing that the Democratic vote had an even larger drop off of 238 voters, compared to 57 fewer Republican voters. While going to 0 is huge in percentage terms, it's not that significant if the number wasn't high to begin with. Maybe a more general "why don't many Republicans vote in NYC mayor primaries" would lead to a more thorough answer about the reasons for this behavior?

Comment: I agree this wasn't worded the best

Comment: @Bobson that's the general election - the last Republican primary was in 2013 as there was only one candidate in 2017. There was only one voter in that precinct in 2013's primary - even lower.

Comment: @CDJB - Ack, you're right.  I had the 2017 primary up earlier, but I navigated back to the wrong one when I was ready to write it up.  Thanks for catching that.

Answer (score 1):

No Republican candidate has any chance of winning the election in the general election.

People don't bother to vote in a primary when none of the candidates has any chance of winning, and the election doesn't have great symbolic meaning rooted in tradition and habit.